# Rails nested ressources and collection_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two models with a has_many/belongs_to association.

```
#Projects.rb
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tasks
end

#Task.rb
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
end
```

Their routes are nested like this:

```
#Routes.rb
resources :projects do
  resources :tasks
end
```

I want to make a form_for creating a new task.

But I want to make it so that the user can choose which project the task belongs to using the `collection_select` method.

My problem is that form_for takes project as one of the parameters to create the form action.

```
= form_for @task do |f|
```

Raises a NoMethodError:

```
undefined method tasks_path for <#class:blablabla>
```

I know I can solve this by putting in the argument for form_for but the idea is to make it a part of the form with 'collection_select'.

How can I solve this?

Comment: See the answer below.  The issue is that you have a nested route for tasks, which essentially means that the "project" is always going to be part of the path for a task.  /projects/1/tasks/new would be a path to put up a form to add a new task to project 1, for instance.  If you want to choose a project for a task then tasks needs to be a resource at the top level.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a separate route entry only for `new` and `create`

```
#Routes.rb
resources :projects do
  resources :tasks, except: [:new, :create]
end
resources :tasks, only: [:new, :create]
```

The downside is you may need a separate form for :new vs :edit

Comment: I did consider this solution. It feels very not-railsy, but I will take what I can have. Thanks!

Comment: Well if you were to do it railsy then you would select the project first and not give the user a choice of projects on the new.